# Find file hosted by python server

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

I have a `localhost:5000` port that is hosted by `python3` server in `ubuntu`. How to i know which file it serves without knowing anything extra?

I am using `lsof -i :5000` and i only know that it is hosted by python 3.
I am trying to locate the file/folder hosted by that that without any extra knowledge given. The thing i know that yes, there is some file being hosted at port 5000 using python3. But i dunno what is the name of the file hosted and which directory it is located.

Is that possible and what command do i need to get all file/folder hosted by it?

Comment: `fuser 5000/tcp` should tell you what `.py` file is used by the process that listens on port 5000, however this question belongs on superuser and not stackoverflow

Comment: @DeepSpace I try that command and it only returns 5000/tcp : {PID}

Comment: How about `fuser 5000/tcp -v` ?

Comment: 5000/tcp:            ubuntu    PID F.... python3 where F..... is under ACCESS column but it is truncated. is that the file path ?